# Simple proofs of the following identity related to the roots of units

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm looking for simple proofs of the following identity
$$
z_k\Pi_{j\neq k}(z_k-z_j)=n,
$$
where each $z_j$ is the n-th root of the unit, i.e., $z_j=e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}$,$j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

$$\prod_{j\neq k} (z-z_j) = \frac{z^n-1}{z-z_k}$$

Take the limit as $z\to z_k$ and you get $\prod_{j\neq k}(z_k-z_j)=nz_k^{n-1}$. Multiply both sides by $z_k$.

More generally, if $f(z)$ is a polynomial with $z_1,\dots,z_n$ all the roots, with possible repetitions, then for any $k$:

$$\prod_{j\neq k} (x_k-x_j) = f'(x_k).$$

Answer (score 2):

If you divide your identity by $z_k^n = 1$ then you get
$$ \prod_{j \neq 0} (1-z_j) = n, $$
and we will prove that instead. We know that
$$ \prod_{j \neq 0} (t-z_j) = \frac{\prod_j (t-z_j)}{t-1} = \frac{t^n-1}{t-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} t^i. $$
Substituting $t = 1$, we get the identity.